# Different citation styles for multiple bibliography

Tags: natbib, multibib

I've a document with multiple bibliography and I'm desperately trying to have different styles for `\cite` options. I'd like an author-year style for bibliography, while a numeric style is better for sitography.

The sample below doesn't work; the compilation throws an error saying `! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` So, I'm forced to use also `numbers` or `super` option when declaring `natbib`. However, in doing so, I lost the ability to have author-year citations.

Is there any workaround to this problem? I've tried a lot of different combinations until now but I haven't found yet a way to achieve this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{url} % needed for sitography
\usepackage[square,sort,comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage{multibib} % needed for multiple bibliography
\newcites{web}{{Sitografia}} 
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BODY
\chapter{First}
a bib citation here \cite{Lipczak2009} and a web citation here \citeweb{web:wiki}\\.    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\cleardoublepage
\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
%\bibliographystyle{natbib_ita}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SITOGRAPHY
\cleardoublepage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Sitografia}
\nociteweb{*}
\bibliographystyleweb{plain} 
\bibliographyweb{sitography}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib

```
@article{Lipczak2009,
abstract = {replaced text},
author = {Lipczak, Marek and Hu, Yeming and Kollet, Yael and Milios, Evangelos},
issn = {16130073},
journal = {CEUR Workshop Proceedings},
pages = {157--172},
title = {{Tag sources for recommendation in collaborative tagging systems}},
volume = {497},
year = {2009}
}
```

sitography.bib

```
@misc{web:wiki,
title = {{Wikipedia.it}},
howpublished = {\url{https://it.wikipedia.org/}}
}
```